# How to get Solidity revert/require error reason in Python and web3.py

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, web3py

I am trying to catch **require()** errors when the transaction is reverted , but I get transaction's hash, I am using **web3.py**

```py
def addParticipants(request):
    web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(settings.Blockchain_IP_address, request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))
    project_address = '0x93aeD90401a182247EE28848229531bC78053cd6'
    project = web3.eth.contract(address=project_address,
                                abi=Project_sol.abi,
                                bytecode=Project_sol.bytecode)
    func_to_call = 'addParticipant'
    addParticipant = project.functions[func_to_call]
    result = addParticipant(settings.ADMIN_ACCOUNT,0).transact(  {'from': settings.ADMIN_ACCOUNT, 'gasLimit': '6000000', 'gasPrice': '0', 'gas': 600000})
    web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(result)
    print(result)
```

Solidity method:

```
  function addParticipant(address _Participant, uint _weight)public isOwner returns (bool) {
    require(_weight!=0,"weight cannot be null");
    require(status,"this Donation is closed");

    Participants[_Participant].weight = _weight;
    Participants[_Participant].status = true;
    ParticipantsIndex[ParticipantsIndexSize] = _Participant;
    ParticipantsIndexSize++;

    emit ParticipantAction(_Participant, 'added');
    return true;
  }
```

the function should throw errors says

> "weight cannot be null"

Comment: Could you point to web3.py documentation which shows it is expected to behave as you've described?

Comment: @EdNoepel , in the documentation there is no example on errors,but i had an experience using web3.php and i got the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer in a similar question found here: [Solidity "require" error message in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727267/solidity-require-error-message-in-python)

You can use the [fetch_transaction_revert_reason](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary/eth_defi.revert_reason.fetch_transaction_revert_reason.html#eth_defi.revert_reason.fetch_transaction_revert_reason) method of the [web3-ethereum-defi](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi).
You simply import the module and if the transaction is not executed because of a require() error you can use the following command:

```
fetch_transaction_revert_reason(web3, tx_hash)
```

This will create a string containing the text 'execution reverted' followed by the error message provided by the require method.

In your case you could add before the receipt command the following line:

```
fetch_transaction_revert_reason(web3, result)
```

This way this should be printed in your console:

> execution reverted: weight cannot be null

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
def addParticipants(request):
   web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(settings.Blockchain_IP_address, request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))
   project_address = '0x93aeD90401a182247EE28848229531bC78053cd6'
   project = web3.eth.contract(address=project_address,
                            abi=Project_sol.abi,
                            bytecode=Project_sol.bytecode)
   func_to_call = 'addParticipant'
   addParticipant = project.functions[func_to_call]
   result = addParticipant(settings.ADMIN_ACCOUNT,0).transact(  {'from': settings.ADMIN_ACCOUNT, 'gasLimit': '6000000', 'gasPrice': '0', 'gas': 600000})
web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(result)

   if result.status == 0:
      try:
          result = w3.eth.call(tx)
      except ValueError as e:
          print(e)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from web3 import exceptions

try:
    result = addParticipant(......)
    web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(result)
    print(result)
except exceptions.SolidityError as error:
    print(error)
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question (code-only answers are not that great)…

Comment: Hi, reverted transaction throws SolidityError, you can catch it with Exceptions handling
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp
and handle the error as you wish. In the code above error is just printed.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is factually incorrect, because this is not how it works.